# two nearly equal jQuery functions; one works with IE, one doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery

I included two nearly identical jQuery functions in [my homepage](http://www.umiwebservice.com/) which should increase or decrease the font-size.

They both work perfectly fine with FireFox, but the increaseFont-function doesn't work with the Internet Explorer (it actually works one time, but not multiple times).

Usually I'd say I made a mistake, but since it works with FireFox I guess it's Internet Explorer-related. Of course I did the usual research but haven't found anything relevant.

My question is: What's the problem and is there a solution or workaround?

Here's the code I used:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // Reset Font Size 
    var originalFontSize = jQuery('html').css('font-size');
    jQuery(".resetFont").click(function() {
        jQuery('div#mainContainer').css('font-size', originalFontSize);
    });
    // Increase Font Size
    jQuery(".increaseFont").click(function() {
        var currentFontSize = jQuery('div#mainContainer').css('font-size');
        var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
        var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum * 1.05;
        jQuery('div#mainContainer').css('font-size', newFontSize);
        return false;
    });
    // Decrease Font Size
    jQuery(".decreaseFont").click(function() {
        var currentFontSize = jQuery('div#mainContainer').css('font-size');
        var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
        var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum * 0.95;
        jQuery('div#mainContainer').css('font-size', newFontSize);
        return false;
    });
});​
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you debug this, is your currentFontSize coming back as '10px' rather than just '10' in IE?

Comment: Can you recreate a demo in http://jsfiddle.net/ and post it here.

Comment: You can use syntax like `.css('font-size','+=1px')` btw, see: http://jsfiddle.net/cwK8w/1/

Comment: What version(s) of IE have you tested this with? It works fine for me in IE9.

Comment: Not related, but parseFloat only takes the one parameter. The second (which I assume is meant to be the radix) is only for parseInt

Comment: @bazmegakapa - he does, but he also says it doesn't work, so just trying to narrow it down.

Comment: I tested it with IE8. I also tested it with the IE-Tester for all versions, but I don't know how reliable this tool really is. Also, it probably has nothing to do with whether the value comes with 'px' or without because the decreaseFont-function works the same way.

Comment: I would not trust any browser, especially IE, with any pixel value that's not represented as a whole number.  There will be rounding issues and they'll all be different.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var originalFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');

            $('.resetFont').live('click', function () {
                $('div#mainContainer').css('font-size', originalFontSize);
            });

            $('.increaseFont').live('click', function () {
                $('div#mainContainer').css('font-size', (parseFloat($('div#mainContainer').css('font-size'), 10) * 1.05));
            });

            $('.decreaseFont').live('click', function () {
                $('div#mainContainer').css('font-size', (parseFloat($('div#mainContainer').css('font-size'), 10) * 0.95));
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        a
        {
            font-size: larger;
            font-weight: bolder;
            color: Green;
            margin: 0 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>   
    <div>
        <a class="decreaseFont">A-</a> <a class="resetFont">A</a> <a class="increaseFont">A+</a>
    </div>
    <div id="mainContainer">
        Hi.. How r u? Testing... Teasting...
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```